# Using TcpClient to connect and Send commands to smtp.gmail.com

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I am unable to send any command through smtp.gmail.com.

I can see some mixed up characters when I connect with 465 as the port number.

If I use any other port number like 25 or 587, it fails with "The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format."

Here's my code..

```
 public delegate void StatusUpdateEvents(object o, clsStatusEventHandler e);
    public event StatusUpdateEvents statusupdate;
    clsStatusEventHandler objStatus = new clsStatusEventHandler();
    public bool EnableSSL { get; set; }
    public string strIpAddress { get; set; }
    public int portNo { get; set; }

    static public string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
    {

        byte[] toEncodeAsBytes

              = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);

        string returnValue

              = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);

        return returnValue;

    }



    public TcpClient GetTcpClient()
    {
      if(smtpTcpClient==null) smtpTcpClient = new TcpClient();

      return smtpTcpClient;
    }
    public TcpClient ConnectTcpClient()
    {
        if (smtpTcpClient.Connected) smtpTcpClient.Close();
        smtpTcpClient.Connect(strIpAddress, portNo);
        return smtpTcpClient;
    }
  public  void UpdateStatus(string strStatus)
    {
       objStatus.strStatus = strStatus;
     if (statusupdate!=null) statusupdate(this, objStatus);
    }



    bool CertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {

        return true;

    }

    public StreamReader GetReadStream()
    {
        if (EnableSSL == true)
        {
            smtpNetworkStream = smtpTcpClient.GetStream();

            if (smtpStreamReader == null) { smtpStreamReader = new StreamReader(GetSslStream()); }
            return smtpStreamReader;
        }
        else
        {
            smtpNetworkStream = smtpTcpClient.GetStream();
            if (smtpStreamReader == null) { smtpStreamReader = new StreamReader(smtpNetworkStream); }
            return smtpStreamReader;
        }
    }

    public StreamWriter GetWriteStream()
    {
        if (EnableSSL == true)
        {
            smtpNetworkStream = smtpTcpClient.GetStream();

            //  readerSmtp = new StreamReader(new System.Net.Security.SslStream(clientSmtp.GetStream(), true, CertificateValidationCallback));

            if (smtpStreamWriter == null) { smtpStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(GetSslStream()); }

            return smtpStreamWriter;
        }
        else
        {
            smtpNetworkStream = smtpTcpClient.GetStream();
            if (smtpStreamWriter == null) { smtpStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(smtpNetworkStream); }

            return smtpStreamWriter;
        }

    }

    SslStream GetSslStream()
    {
        if (sslstream == null) { 
            sslstream = new SslStream(smtpNetworkStream);
           sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient(strIpAddress, null, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls, false);

        }
        return sslstream;
    }

    public void DoConnect(string strIpAddress, int portno,bool EnableSSL) 
    {
        this.strIpAddress = strIpAddress;
        this.portNo = portno;
        try
        {
            UpdateStatus("trying to connect to " + strIpAddress + ":" + portno.ToString());
            smtpTcpClient = GetTcpClient();
            smtpTcpClient.Connect(strIpAddress, portno);

            if(EnableSSL==true)
            {
                this.EnableSSL = EnableSSL;
                smtpNetworkStream = smtpTcpClient.GetStream();

               //sslstream.Write(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("EHLO something123@gmail.com \n"));
               //sslstream.Write(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("STARTTLS \n"));

               smtpStreamReader = GetReadStream();//new StreamReader(new System.Net.Security.SslStream(smtpTcpClient.GetStream(), true,CertificateValidationCallback));
               //readerSmtp = new StreamReader(sslstream);
            }
            else
            {
                EnableSSL = false;
                smtpNetworkStream = smtpTcpClient.GetStream();
                smtpStreamReader = GetReadStream();
             }

            UpdateStatus(readResponse());

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            UpdateStatus("****CONNECTION ERROR****" + "\n" + e.Message);
            smtpTcpClient.Close();
        }

    }
```

Please help me..
Thanks so much in advance..

**Edit: I know about the System.net.mail.smtpclient and other opensource smtp libraries available. But, I cannot use that to manually send smtp commands. This is not for sending e-mails. This is for seeing the email protocol work step by step through SSL.**

Comment: Why dont you use System.Net.Mail instead of TcpClient?

Comment: because I am trying to build something like telnet to manually send commands.

Comment: EHLO,RCPT, and other SMTP commands

Comment: How do you plan on seeing the protocol work, on an encrypted protocol...

Comment: msarchet,unfortunately this is my requirement. I dont have to see whats happening underneath the ssl. I can atleast display whats happening. You can see my code on how im triggering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably just use [System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) as this is what it is designed to be used with

Comment: No,I cannot use that for my project.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I appreciate it. but this wont help me.

Comment: I meant to sy I'm thinking about this

Answer (score -1):

To connect with TcpClient you have to scan DNS before, smtp.gmail.com is not the right server, try this:

```
var tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
tcpclnt.Connect("gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 25);
```